# If statement doesn't catch specific condition in Katalon

Tags: groovy, automation, cucumber, katalon-studio

i wrote a code to meet a condition using if statement in katalon but somehow if statement doesn't catch my condition. 
Here is my code:

```
def ElementChecked =
WebUI.verifyElementChecked(findTestObject('Page_/checkbox_BPKB_assignment'),0,FailureHandling.OPTIONAL)
        if (ElementChecked==true){
            println(">>>>>ALREADY CLICKED")
        }
        else{
            println(">>>>>Not clicked yet")
            WebUI.click(findTestObject('Page_/checkbox_BPKB_assignment'))
            WebUI.click(findTestObject('Page_/button_Submit'))
            WebUI.click(findTestObject('Page_/button_OK'))
        }
```

From code above, element that i want to inspect is radiobutton. so, i make a condition if radiobutton checked then print (">>>>>ALREADY CLICKED) else print(">>>>>Not clicked yet") and do some clicks. But, even if the condition is true it always go to else statement. 
can anyone help me what is wrong with this?

Comment: print your `ElementChecked` (naming is SICK) out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have some bsns logic based on is/is not checked, better to work with `org.openqa.selenium.WebElement`.

**Example of checking radio button state:**

**Keyword definition:**

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement
import com.kms.katalon.core.webui.driver.DriverFactory


public class Q58713480 {

    @Keyword
    def ElementChecked(TestObject testObject) {
        WebDriver driver = DriverFactory.getWebDriver()
        WebElement element = WebUI.findWebElement(testObject, 5)
        if (element.isSelected()) {
            KeywordUtil.logInfo("Element is checked.")
        }
        else {
            KeywordUtil.logInfo("Element is not checked.")
        }
    }
}
```

**Test case:**

```
WebUI.openBrowser('')
WebUI.maximizeWindow()
WebUI.navigateToUrl("http://www.echoecho.com/htmlforms10.htm")
WebUI.waitForPageLoad(60)

CustomKeywords.'Q58713480.ElementChecked'(findTestObject('radio1'))
WebUI.click(findTestObject('radio1'))
CustomKeywords.'Q58713480.ElementChecked'(findTestObject('radio1'))

WebUI.closeBrowser()
```

**Output:**

```
...
2019-11-14 13:25:14.514 DEBUG testcase.question58713480                - 2: maximizeWindow()
2019-11-14 13:25:15.705 DEBUG testcase.question58713480                - 3: navigateToUrl("http://www.echoecho.com/htmlforms10.htm")
2019-11-14 13:25:18.382 DEBUG testcase.question58713480                - 4: waitForPageLoad(60)
2019-11-14 13:25:18.720 DEBUG testcase.question58713480                - 5: Q58713480.ElementChecked(findTestObject("radio1"))
2019-11-14 13:25:19.298 INFO  com.kms.katalon.core.util.KeywordUtil    - Element is not checked.
2019-11-14 13:25:19.299 INFO  k.k.c.m.CustomKeywordDelegatingMetaClass - Q58713480.ElementChecked is PASSED
2019-11-14 13:25:19.299 DEBUG testcase.question58713480                - 6: click(findTestObject("radio1"))
2019-11-14 13:25:19.568 DEBUG testcase.question58713480                - 7: Q58713480.ElementChecked(findTestObject("radio1"))
2019-11-14 13:25:19.726 INFO  com.kms.katalon.core.util.KeywordUtil    - Element is checked.
2019-11-14 13:25:19.726 INFO  k.k.c.m.CustomKeywordDelegatingMetaClass - Q58713480.ElementChecked is PASSED
2019-11-14 13:25:19.727 DEBUG testcase.question58713480                - 8: closeBrowser()
2019-11-14 13:25:20.702 INFO  c.k.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor   - END Test Cases/question58713480
```

**And the 'radio1' test object (created manualy):**
[image: radio1 test object]

Comment: hi @pburgr, thank you for your answer it really helps me. Actually i've already implemented what you've said and after analyze more i've found out what problem is. The problem is because sometime automation run too fast so web element didn't get real condition. Solution that i implement is to add "waitForElementPresent" then everything's good right now.
Thank you